# Run multiple commands from a file after logging into PuTTY from a bat file

Tags: terminal, putty, batch-file

I have written a bat file in which I have the following:

```
putty.exe -t -load "ABC" -l username -pw password -m "C:\Users\pathasai\Desktop\abc.txt"
```

In my abc.txt I have written some commands which I want to be executed on PuTTY itself, but when I run the bat file, I am not able to run the commands. I am getting the error command not found. For instance, let us say our abc.txt has just one command: `pbrun`. It is saying command not found. (I get this error on the putty terminal.)

How do I get multiple commands to run one after the other from the abc.txt file?

Comment: It should work. Can you connect to the client normally using putty?

It worked for me with `putty.exe -ssh me@192.168.100.194 -m test.txt` where test.txt contains three lines: `echo "hello"
echo "goodbye"
sleep 10s` - in this case it is a linux that I am connecting to and so the saved file test.txt (abc.txt in your case) needs to be saved with Linux line ends i.e. LF not CR + LF.

Comment: Hi i am working in windows...and it is working when i normally open putty and connect to the sever and run the commands ..... But with the way i am doing its crating trouble.... And i didnt get your last line ...

Comment: yep, so was I, I mean the machine I was connecting *to* was linux. If you want to connect to a windows machine it needs to be set up for such remote connection. What type of machine are you connecting to?

Comment: Ummmbthat i need to chk for.....but can u let me know what would be the reason for tgat command not found as from putty directly it is working fine but from txt file its not ..... Pbrun command not found ..... Any special things i need to add to the text file? Or smething like that?

Comment: probably because you save the file with windows line ending so it sees pbrun\x013 i.e. with a control character at the end. If you use editor EditPad Pro you can choose to save with Unix line endings (Convert/To UNIX). Other decent editors will have similar option - but not Windows Notepad.

Comment: Ok so u suggest to oonvert that file into unix endings ...?

Comment: yes, that is my suggestion.

Comment: What is your SSH server? OpenSSH or other?

Answer (score 2):

> **run multiple commands from a file after logging into putty from a bat file**

You can't log-in to PuTTY. PuTTY is an SSH *client* application which has no authentication.

You can use PuTTY to log-in to a server computer which is providing an SSH service. Typically this would be a Linux server. It is the server that requires you log-in to it.

> **In my abc.txt I have written some commands which I want to be executed on putty itself**

You cannot run arbitrary commands on PuTTY itself.

You can use PuTTY to run commands in a shell on the server.

Those commands must be present on the server and supported by the server's operating system.

> **our abc.txt has just one command: pbrun. It is saying command not found.**

That means that the command `pbrun` is **not** a valid command on the server's operating system (this is nothing to do with PuTTY).

Not all Linux servers have `pbrun`:

```
$ man pbrun
No manual entry for pbrun
$ pbrun
-bash: pbrun: command not found
$ uname
Linux
$
```

You must also be careful with line-endings on your commands. Windows files edited with notepad are likely to have lines ending with the two ASCII control characters Carriage-Return (CR or Control-M or ^M) and Line-Feed (LF or Control-J or ^J). I would expect PuTTY to take care of this, but it may not (I have not tested this).

```
$ pwd
/
$ pwd^M
: command not found
$
```

---

Update

I used Notepad to create this file, "commands.txt":

```
echo "this command works"
echo
echo "this command works too"
sleep 20 # so I can see
```

I used this command:

```
C:\temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe" rgb@server -m commands.txt
```

I got this result:

```
this command works

                  this command works too
```

I imagine there is some issue with `stty` or PuTTY settings affecting newline operation, but basically the `-m` mechanism works and, with some diligent effort, I would expect to be able to make it do useful work correctly.